# FX (efeito sonoro) em questão de UX, é uma boa prática para sistemas que rodam em browsers?

Tags: ux

Estou fazendo algumas finalizações para um release, e tive a ideia de colocar alguns efeitos sonoros, como `'crack'` ao fechar modal, ou `'pin'` ao alertar algo.

Bom, pessoalmente eu não gostei, mas me pareceu intuitivo, e também tive a impressão de que deixa o o usuário mais 'amigo' do sistema, pois ele da uns sinais a mais do que é que ele está fazendo.

- Minha dúvida é o titulo, aplicar efeitos
  sonoros a interações é uma boa
  prática em sistemas que rodam em browsers ?
- Se sim, existe algum preset padrão que seja de uso recomendado pra cada tipo de interação ? (fechar, alertar, esmaecer e etc...).
- Se não é uma boa prática, por quê ?

Contexto de minha aplicação:

1. Mobile e Desktop são aplicações diferentes que fazem coisas diferentes, então os efeitos são apenas para desktop.
2. O publico/usuários são bem especificos, contadores e outras pessoas que trabalhem no escritório contábil.
3. Todos os usuários podem ou não estar usando headset.
4. O foco do sistema é exibição, tratamento e automação de manutenção de dados, não o uso para efetuar tarefas/obrigações.

Comment: Eu particularmente, acho muito empolgante quando um software me responde desta forma. Me mostra que "alguém" teve um certo cuidado a mais ao entregar essa aplicação e muitas vezes pode ser mesmo intuitivo. Agora já na parte técnica, só tem que ver a questão do contexto né? Ele sempre vai rodar no navegador de um computador? Vai rodar mobile? Será acessado em ambiente coorporativo, onde na maioria das vezes o som é desativado?  Eu acho muito válido como um extra, mas sem dependências dessa funcionalidade. Entende? E se me permite, parabéns pela iniciativa.

Comment: Vou dar um atualizada na pergunta com o contexto do software, bons apontamentos.!

Comment: Eu não sou um expert em ux, mas acredito que, dependendo da forma que utilizada, se torna sim uma boa prática. Claro que, na maioria das vezes, devido ao contexto, os usuários nem vão perceber esta ação, porque provavelmente não terão o som do computador ativado. Porém, para um deficiente visual por exemplo, isso seria sim uma mão na roda, dependendo da forma que utilizado. Então, finalizando. Sim, acredito ser uma boa prática, mas como tudo na vida, isso se bem executada. Seu exemplo dos modais parecem ser adequados, mas ainda pode ser estendido para ações de salvar, cancelar, etc. Acredito..

Comment: Se fosse em questão de gamificar uma aplicação, talvez seja interessante

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após algumas análises de uso, foi identificado no nosso contexto, que efeitos sonoros não são tão ***User Friendly*** como são em outros contextos.

***Motivos***:

1. Ambiente corporativo em grupo - Os usuários precisam se comunicar por voz um com o outro através de seus headsets.
2. Alguns usuários não utilizam headset e não é viável permitir que o som de seus PCs permaneçam com áudio.
3. Manter um padrão entre aplicação WEB DESKTOP e aplicação MOBILE, inviável manter FX em uma e em outra não.
4. Funcionalidade não planejada no inicio do projeto, e muitas alterações precisariam ser feitas para um resultado não tão eficiente/não necessário.